# How to reverse a double loop?

Tags: r, loops

I currently have a double loop that prints objects from list into a grid based upon a given number of rows and columns.  My issue is that I want to provide the users a "byrow" option so they can decide to fill across the columns or rows first. The only way I've gotten it to work so far is by doubling my code and changing the loop order which seems incredibly inefficient. A much simplified version of my code is below.

Please let me know if any more information is required. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
plot ( x = 1:4 , y = 1:4 , type = "n")

w <- list ( "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" ,"e" , "f")

nrow <- 3 
ncol <- 2

if (length(w) > nrow * ncol ) warning("NOT ENOUGH rows/columns")


for ( i in 1:nrow) for (j in 1:ncol){
    if( !length(w) ) break
    text(i,j , w[[1]])
    w <- w[-1]
}
```

EDIT:

Apologies I should have highlighted this more clearly. The above code is a highly simplified version of my actual code. The main list is a list of lists and the function I am using instead of text is not vectorised thus `matrix` won't work for my specific case.

Looking through the provided answers though I have managed to use the `rev` and `expand.grid` functions that others have used to create the following:

```
plot ( x = 1:4 , y = 1:4 , type = "n")

w <- list ( "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" ,"e" )

nrow <- 3 
ncol <- 2
byrow <- T

if (length(w) > nrow * ncol ) warning("NOT ENOUGH rows/columns")

grid <- expand.grid(1:nrow , 1:ncol) 
if ( !byrow) grid <- rev(grid)
grid <- grid[1:length(w),]

mapply( text , grid[,1] ,grid[,2] , w)
```

Am still interested to see if there is a better way of doing this though still.

Comment: I might be missing something, but are you trying to write an inefficient version of the matrix function?

Comment: "*Am still interested to see if there is a better way of doing this though still.*" To work on this productively I think we would need to see an example that more closely resembles your actual data. And probably in a new question, don't want to move the goalposts here too much.

Answer (score 3):

`text()` is vectorized - and plays well with matrices (which have a `byrow` argument already). No loop is needed. Change `byrow` to `TRUE` at the top if you want to switch it up.

```
byrow = FALSE

plot ( x = 1:4 , y = 1:4 , type = "n")
w <- list ( "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" ,"e" , "f") ## why a list, not a vector??

nrow <- 3 
ncol <- 2
if (length(w) > nrow * ncol ) warning("NOT ENOUGH rows/columns")

# no loop needed
mat = matrix(unlist(w), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, byrow = byrow)
text(x = expand.grid(1:nrow, 1:ncol), labels = mat)
```

`matrix` also has it's own warning if the rows and column numbers aren't don't work out - but if it can recycle evenly it will silently fill in, so your warning may be preferable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply @Gregor.  Unfortunately this doesn't work in my particular case. My list is a list of lists and the function I am using isn't vecotrised. Apologies I should have made this more clear in the original question.  The example code I provided was a very simplified version of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38836931/2761575) by @Gregor, for your simple example it is better to use `matrix()` together with vectorised capability of `text()` than to use a double `for` loop.

However, if there is more going on inside the loops of your actual production code rather than the minimal example, which requires you to use a double loop, then you can do it with loops using something along these lines:

```
w <- list ( "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" ,"e" , "f")
nrow <- 3 
ncol <- 2

f1 <- function(w, nrow, ncol, byrow=F) {
  if (length(w) > nrow * ncol ) warning("NOT ENOUGH rows/columns")
  size <- c(nrow,ncol)
  if (byrow) size <- rev(size) 
  for ( i in 1:size[1]) for (j in 1:size[2]){
    pos <- c(i,j)
    if (byrow) pos <- rev(pos)
    text(pos[1],pos[2] , w[[(i-1)*size[2]+j]]) 
  }
}

plot ( x = 1:4 , y = 1:4 , type = "n")
f1 (w, nrow, ncol, byrow=F) 

plot ( x = 1:4 , y = 1:4 , type = "n")
f1 (w, nrow, ncol, byrow=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is to order the `coords` matrix by either `x` values or `y` values, and then add the text labels to the matrix.

```
byrow <- TRUE
coords <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(1:nrow, 1:ncol))
names(coords) <- c("x","y")
if(!byrow) coords <- coords[order(coords[,"x"]),]
coords[["labels"]] <- unlist(w)
with(coords, {
  plot(x=1:4, y=1:4, type="n")
  text(x=x, y=y, labels=labels)
})
```